# Particle emitter not rendering but particles are rendering

Tags: rendering, particles

[image][image]Okay; Im rendering a shot where the ground burst open, so I have a grass particle simulation on my ground. There is a large column of dirt that shows up in my rendered viewport but disappears when I click render. The strange part is, the grass particles still show up. The object doesn't have rendering disabled and, under particle settings, rendering emitter is definitely enabled. Weirder still is that when I disable the particles, the object will render. I have the exact same particle settings on other objects in the scene but they render just fine. Also, the duplicate setting are set to none and I have no clue what's going on. HELPP MEEE

Comment: Can you upload a .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)?

Comment: Please show a Blender screen capture with the 3D View and the Particle Panel in Blender.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I added a screen capture

Comment: UPDATE so I decided to try duplicating the object and moving it to another layer and NOW ITS RENDERING!!! I'm really confused but I think it's just best not to question it... :/

Comment: Please know that Blender has elaborate settings .... you can choose to render only some layers which is a convenience at certain times.  Its also easy to view different layers by intention or the random hit of the main keyboard numbers.  All the flexibility of Blender allows for some misadventures.  It is easy to lose track of all your actions especially in the beginning ... and ever after in using Blender. If this is a consistent problem do address it.  If it only happens once, consider the issue addressed.  You will have many other issues in Blender to consume your time.

Comment: You may want to put your own actions as an answer so people will immediately know you have some solution.

Comment: The Render Layers active panel may be inspected to make sure you have the settings you desire.  If I could place a picture in a comment I would.

Comment: Could you upload your blend?

Comment: UPDATE now it doesn't render again- I didn't change anything besides baking the particle sim. Is this just a bug?

Comment: UPDATE I freed the bake and now it's rendering again- somehow baking the grass particle sim made the dirt not render. Not sure that this is a permanent fix but I hope it will last this time

Comment: UPDATE Now not rendering AGAIN!!! IM SO CONFUSED!!!!!!