# My mesh is not rendering, but my particle system is. How do I make it all visible in during a render?

Tags: rendering, particles

When I added a particle system to an object it made the rest of the mesh it was attached to not appear when rendered. However, it is viable in the viewport.
I have made sure that the eye and camera icons are checked. I have also checked to make sure that the rendered layers node is attached to the composite node.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59005/particle-emitter-not-rendering-but-particles-are-rendering

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default Blender does have the particle emitter enabled for rendering, though perhaps you have turned it off?

[image: render emitter screenshot]

It would be helpful in answering the question if you could provide a .blend that shows the issue. Blender is quite complex and guessing based on a description is not always easy.

Comment: Checking that box fixed the problem for me. Thank you.